# Only 1 product adding to order when creating orders programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, orders, programmatically

I am in a process of creating orders programatically in Magento 2.
below is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Eight65media\MpowerSync\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
class Data extends AbstractHelper{

protected $scopeConfig;
protected $loggerInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
) {

    $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_product = $product;
    $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
    $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->order = $order;
}    


public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
    $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
    if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
        //If not avilable then create this customer 
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                ->setStore($store)
                ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
        $customer->save();
    }

    $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
    $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
    $quote->setStore($store);
    // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
    $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
    $quote->setCurrency();
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

    //add items in quote
    foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
        echo "+ ".$item['product_id']."</br>";
        $product = $this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
        //$product->setPrice($item['price']);
        $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
    }

    //Set Address to quote
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

    $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                    ->collectShippingRates()
                    ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
    $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory

    // Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
    $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

    // Collect Totals
    $quote->collectTotals();

    // Create Order From Quote
    $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());
    $orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
    $order = $this->order->load($orderId);

    $order->setEmailSent(0);
    $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
    if($order->getEntityId()){
        $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
    }else{
        $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
    }
    echo $result['order_id'];
    //return $result;
}//end of function create order
}
```

> Below is my sample data set:

```
$tempOrder=[
 'currency_id'  => 'USD',
 'email'        => 'testmuja@muja.com', //buyer email id
 'shipping_address' =>[
        'firstname'    => 'mujiko', //address Details
        'lastname'     => 'jikimo',
        'street' => 'xxxxx',
        'city' => 'xxxxx',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region' => '12',
        'postcode' => '43244',
        'telephone' => '52332',
        'fax' => '32423',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
             ],
       'items'=> [ //array of product which order you want to create
                  ['product_id'=>'1','qty'=>4],
                  ['product_id'=>'10','qty'=>3]

                ]
    ];
```

What my issue is order, is creating, but the products are not adding properly.
Only 1 product is adding to the order, but first product added to the order with the second product price and qty of the product will be a total products in order.
Ex:

```
['product_id'=>'1','qty'=>4],
['product_id'=>'10','qty'=>3]
```

From above product array name of the **`product_id 1 -`** **Product 1**, price **10.00**

Name of the **`product_id 10 -`** **product 2**, price **20.00**

In my order the product is save as **product 1** with price of Product 2(**20**) qty is **7**

Any help highly appreciate and almost 3 days tried in several ways and still fail.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**:
This happens because, in `$quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));`. `$product`  is always the same instance of the `Product` model.

**Solution**:

Replace this in the constructor `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product` with `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory`.
Replace this `$this->_product = $product;` with `$this->_productFactory = $productFactory;` and add the member `$_productFactory` to the class.
Now in the `createMageOrder` method replace

```
$product = $this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
```

with

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item['product_id']);
```

**Better solution**.
Because the `load` method is deprecated you should use repositories.

So replace in your constructor `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product` with `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository` and `$this->_product = $product;` with `$this->_productRepository = $productRepository;`. Also declare the member `$_productRepository` to the class.

Now in the method `createMageOrder` replace

```
$product = $this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
$quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
```

with

```
try {
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($item['product_id']);
    $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    //it means the product does not exist;
    //you can choose to continue without this product or stop the order creation completely here
}
```

Comment: thank you for you explained answer.saved my day